# Powershell Run DLL Method

Tags: .net, powershell, dll

Im trying to run a method from a dll class library I created. The method connects to a database using entity framework. I want this to run on a schedule and thought about using Powershell to call my method.

Using powershell I load the assemblies like so. (I have reduced the paths to the assemblies to make it easier to see)

```
Add-Type -Path "..\EntityFramework.dll"
Add-Type -Path "..\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll"
Add-Type -Path "..\TransMan.Import.Common.dll"
Add-Type -Path "..\TransMan.Data.dll"
```

Then call the method like so.

```
$test = New-Object TransMan.Import.Common.Process
$test.DoWork("","Firstline")
```

However this produces the following error.

> Exception calling "DoWork" with "2" argument(s): "The Entity Framework
>   provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the  application config file
>   for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'
>   could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is
>   used and that the assembly is  available to the running application.

I have tested my dll and its working perfectly from a simple c# console application. But now im at lost to what Im missing. Could anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: What should be the data types from your .DoWork() method? Try to specify values with it's proper data type.

Comment: DoWork() reutrns nothing and accepts two string parameters.